# How to get out Busy Box on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi4, busybox

I'm stuck in the Busy Box and don't find a way out.
Here's what I did:

```
(initramfs) blkid
```

The result:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="system-boot" LABEL="system-boot" ... TYPE="vfat" ...
/dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL=writable ... TYPE="ext4" ...
```

What I then did:

```
fsck /dev/mmcblk0p1 -y
```

Which didn't gave any feedback. Then I tried this:

```
fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2 -y
```

The result:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36.1
e2fsck 1.45.7 (28-Jan-2021)
writable: revovering journal
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clearm but journal has data.

fsck.ext4: unable to set superblock flags on writable

writable: ********* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors *********
```

Now the Question:

- How do I get out there?
- Why does it appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with an SD card on my Raspberry PI, did a clone of the broken SD card to a good one using WIN32 Disk Imager.

The new card was then successfully verified by fsck and started properly.

Of course, you might be able to do it on another Linux system using

```
'dd bs=1M if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/home/user/backup.img'...
```